# BorderContainer with text is not showing buttonMode correctly

Tags: apache-flex

In my code, I have a list made up of items from a dataprovider. The itemRenderer for the list consists of a BorderContainer with text in it. I'm mimicking a row of buttons on a scrolling list. I'd like the cursor to change to the hand cursor as it passes over the "button", but the pointer only changes in the part of the BorderContainer that isn't covered by the text.

[image: pointer over the BorderContainer] [image: pointer over text]

I've set the buttonMode to true for the list, the BorderContainer, and the text, so why isn't the cursor changing when passing over the text?

This is the list code

```
<s:List id="listProject" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" allowMultipleSelection="false"
                        click="listProject_clickHandler(event)" itemRenderer="ProjectRenderer"
                        dataProvider="{listProjects}" creationComplete="listProject_creationCompleteHandler(event)" buttonMode="true">
```

And this is the renderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="true">

    <!--<s:Label text="{data.header}"/>-->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="hovered"/>
        <s:State name="selected"/>
    </s:states>

    <!--<s:Image source.normal="{data.image1}" source.hovered="{data.image2}"/>-->

    <s:BorderContainer width="200" height="50" backgroundColor="{data.color}"
                   borderColor.selected="#FFFFFF" borderVisible.normal="false"
                   borderVisible.selected="true" borderWeight.selected="4" borderStyle.selected="inset" buttonMode="true">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center"/>
        </s:layout>
        <mx:Text width="200" text="{data.header}" selectable="false"
                 color="#FFFFFF" fontSize="15" fontWeight="bold" leading="0" textAlign="center" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true"/>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Spark [Label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) instead of mx:Text and you'll be fine.

Also, there's some redundancy in your code. I took the liberty of trimming it down a little:

```
<s:BorderContainer width="200" height="50" backgroundColor="{data.color}"
                   borderColor.selected="#FFFFFF" borderVisible.normal="false"
                   borderVisible.selected="true" borderWeight.selected="4"
                   borderStyle.selected="inset" buttonMode="true">

    <s:Label text="{data.label}" color="#FFFFFF" fontSize="15" fontWeight="bold"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

This will also fix that nasty jumpiness of the text when hovered or selected.

Comment: Thanks, although I still needed the width and textAlign properties, since I had some text that is split into two lines.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you do not need interaction with mx:Text, you can set mouseChildren property of its parent to false. It will fix the problem. Here is a short example:

```
<s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:BorderContainer width="200" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" mouseChildren="false">
        <mx:Text text="No many text" selectable="false" />                  
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, although I decided to go with the Spark solution proposed by RIAstar.